# Getting user input data in FormEvents::SUBMIT

Tags: forms, symfony, events, form-submit

I am looking for a way to get user data in the `formEvents::SUBMIT` event.

I can get it in `formEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` using

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function() {
    //...
    $userInput = $event->getData());
    //...
});
```

I can get it in `formEvents::POST_SUBMIT` using

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function() {
    //...
    $userInput = $event->getForm()->getViewData()
    //...
});
```

But in `formEvents::SUBMIT` I cannot find where, though I read it can be accessed:
[Symfony2: dynamic generation of embedded form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705914/symfony2-dynamic-generation-of-embedded-form)

I can find other project getting data using the same method as `PRE_SUBMIT`, for instance here:
https://github.com/Klerik/web-dersen/blob/65ba1bafa574dc2bda6dd2bb738fe0d33a06bf71/src/Catalog/FilmsBundle/Form/EventListener/UploadFileSubscriber.php

or there:
https://github.com/alexandresalome/bros/blob/59c111eb481c2fd672f3646390455ddad65dd800/src/Bros/ServerBundle/Form/Type/BrowserType.php

Though in my situation I test with user input that does not fit the Normalisation - `$event->getForm()['field']->getData()` sends an object without the user data which have been refused.
Still I want to retrieve user input to:
* change accordingly (testing data validity) my current form (which cannot be done in `POST_SUBMIT`),
* use my form related object (not available in `PRE_SUBMIT`)

**EDIT**

Here are the relevant parts of the ...Type Class :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, Array $options)
{
    $adminUserQuery = $options['admin_user_query'];

    $builder
        ->add('admin_user', 'model', Array( //using Propel as ORM
            'label' => FALSE,
            'multiple' => FALSE,
            'expanded' => FALSE,
            'class' => 'App\\CoreBundle\\Model\\AdminUser',
            'query' => $adminUserQuery,
            'empty_value' => 'form.placeholder.admin_user',
            'property' => 'email',
        ));
    //...

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $formEvent)
    {
        var_dump($formEvent->getData(), '---'); // prints: array(1) { ["admin_user"]=> string(17) "test@email.test" }
        var_dump($formEvent->getData()['admin_user'], '---'); // prints: string(15) "test@email.test"
        //...
    });

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $formEvent)
    {
        var_dump($formEvent->getData()); // prints: object(App\CoreBundle\Model\EventUserRole)#1659 {...}
        var_dump($formEvent->getData()->getAdminUser()); // prints: NULL

        //...
    }
    );
}
```

Anyone ?

Comment: Eventually, I made a fix : used `$formEvent->getData()` in `formEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` to get the input in private variable, and change form in `formEvents::SUBMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

In the FormEvents::Submit action, you can do this (assuming you are editing a User):

```php
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function ($event) {
    // Your Entity/Document
    $user = $event->getData();

    // Grab the actual form
    $form = $event->getForm();

    // ...
});
```

Comment: I do get the Form, but I cannot find within the Form the data the user did input in the 'field'. Would you know ?

Comment: If your form represents an entity/document (i.e. User), Symfony sets it in your Entity (or Document) automatically and you can grab it with your entity/document's getters (i.e. $user->getName()). If it's a child form, you can grab it with: $form->get('accounts')->getData(). Did you try the $event->getData() call above?

Comment: sure I did, but Symfony does not store data that does not fit the model - which is the situation I am in. `$user->getName()` gives data that passed validation. My test data does not.

Comment: Is the field you are trying to access a field in your model - it just isn't passing validation? Or is it a field that doesn't exist in your model at all?

Comment: it just isn't passing validation

Comment: If the field is in your model but not passing validation, it should still be set in your entity/document and accessible in the FormEvents::SUBMIT event. I just did a test where I added a min length assertion of 40 characters to an email address on a user document. Hit submit, and $user = $event->getData(); $user->getEmail() still gives me the email address in the SUBMIT event.. despite the fact that Symfony threw a validation error against that field. Can you post the relevant parts? Also what version of Symfony are you running, and have you tried updating to the latest version?

Comment: Here is mu post updated, I am using Symfony 2.5. I will try updating 2.6 - not this week though. The difference with your example is that I want to retrieve data through an entity which does not exist in the default choice list given by the query. And I cannot find the email test no where else... Thank you for your thoughts, it does help already making sure I did get things properly until now.